# How to create a dotted <hr/> tag?

Tags: html, css

How can I create a dotted or any type of hr line (double, dashed etc.) using CSS?

```
<hr style="...what should I write?..." />
```

or is there any other trick?

Comment: tips: If you want to make multiple dotted lines, you can [duplicate it with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482091/3416774)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You could just have `<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />` . That should work.

Comment: Looks awful, one line straight, the other one dotted.

Comment: Set `background-color: transparent` to remove the straight line

Answer (score 32):

```
hr {
    border-top:1px dotted #000;
    /*Rest of stuff here*/
}
```

Answer (score 24):

```
hr {
    border: 1px dotted #ff0000;
    border-style: none none dotted; 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 18):

You can do:

```
<hr style="border: 1px dashed black;" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JMfC9/

Answer (score 9):

The `<hr>` tag is just a short element with a border:

```
<hr style="border-style: dotted;" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
<hr style="border-bottom: dotted 1px #000" />
```