# How to divide <hr> into multiple parts?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like this -

[image]

My approach was to take a hr tag and divide it and try to customize it. But in doing that, I am not getting any result. I need help with getting this logic or if there is a better alternative, please share with me !

Thanks !!

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819864/how-to-create-a-dotted-hr-tag), or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391217/horizontal-line-hr-with-variable-dash-length)? Or is it important that the dashes have varying lengths?

Comment: @lucidbrot This won't work because image asked in question shows dotted line with varying lengths :)

Comment: The question is not about borders... To achieve the same result as on your attached image, use :after and :before with position: absolute, and align them as you wish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set a css border on the top or bottom of the hr and apply the dash setting.

```css
hr {
border-top: 4px dashed red;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<hr>


</body>
</html>
```

Or use multiple hr's set as inline blocks with different widths.

```css
.inlineHr  {
display: inline-block;
border-top: 4px solid black;
}

.hr1 {
width:120px;
}

.hr2 {
width: 60px;
mergin-left: 10px;
}

.hr3 {
width: 20px;
mergin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<hr class='inlineHr hr1' />
<hr class='inlineHr hr2' />
<hr class='inlineHr hr3' />

<p>Here is the following text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work because image asked in question shows dotted line with varying lengths.

Comment: Indeed so I have provided a second option.

Comment: Hey @Pritesh - if that was your downvote can you review your decision against the edit I made?

Comment: I have already removed my down vote the moment you edited :)